# Java heap arguments specified twice, which one will be finally picked

Tags: java

I executed a program java -Xms256m -Xmx1G Sample.java -Xms2G -Xmx6G. I tested the program, it picked the first one i.e -Xms256m -Xmx1G. I was expecting it would pick the latter one. Any documentation where I can find the explanation?

Comment: Shouldn't the parameters after the `Sample.java` be the parameters to the application, not to the JVM?

Comment: The documentation is at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE, and it tells you that basically you have `java [jvm options] source-file [args]`. Everything after the name of the source file is passed as arguments to your program (even if it happens to look like similar to a JVM option).